# Comparing current row and previous row in different columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looks like follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHLXh.png)

for every date changed on original date column will generate a new row recording the previous original order date and current order date.
 I wanna check for the same order (same order number and customer number), the original order date is coming from the current order date, the result I'm expecting looks like follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHLXh.png)

For example, when the original order date (row 2) = the current order date (row 1), it will return T.

Can anyone please help how to generate the process in python?  Thanks a lot

Comment: You probably want `shift`.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve], that means no pictures of code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try masking with df.shift() (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

For instance if you wanted the same column to compare to the previous row, and if the values were equal you set another cell to 0 it would be something like:
df.loc[df.x == df.x.shift(),'y'] = 0 # would make y = 0 wen df.x is equal to the row value above it.

Comment: Thank you, but I wanna compare to different column... like the 2nd row in column A compare to 1st row in column B